# Изменение настроек в OWL Carousel

Tags: jquery

Пользуюсь плагином [OWL Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html).
Нужно изменить его настройки динамически, а именно настройку `items`.
[В демо написано](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/custom.html), что можно изменять только некоторые настройки:

```
$(".play").click(function() {
   owl.trigger('owl.play', 1000); //owl.play event accept autoPlay speed as second parameter
})
```

Каким образом можно изменить настройку `items`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На приведённом Вами сайте также упоминается и `owl.reinit(newOptions)`. Собственно  с помощью этой функции думаю и можно добиться желаемого результата.

Например по клику будем менять с `items=10` на `items=4`

```
// получаем настройки
var owl = $("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel');

// меняем значение items (используя reinit) при клике на #edit
$("#edit").on("click", function() {
    owl.reinit({
        items: 4
    });
});
```

Глянуть пример в работе: [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/d2t81Lbg/show/)

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня почему-то оно не работает.

Comment: @Владимир По ссылке на `jsfiddle` всё вроде работает, следовательно Вам стоит поискать различия Вашего кода с тем, [что работает](http://fiddle.jshell.net/d2t81Lbg/).